# Converting a number to its alphabetical counterpart in lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make a lua script that takes an input of numbers seperated by commas, and turns them into letters, so 1 = a ect, however I have not found a way to do this easily because the string libray outputs a = 97, so I have no clue where to go now, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely just account for the starting value of a-z in the [ascii table.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
function convert(...)
    local ar = {...}
    local con = {}
    for i,v in pairs(ar) do
        table.insert(con, ("").char(v+96))
    end
    return con;
end

for i,v in pairs(convert(1,2,3,4)) do
    print(v)
end
```

Comment: Okay so from this I have `text = io.read()
function convert(...)
local ar = {...}
local con = {}
for i,v in pairs(ar) do
table.insert(con, ("").char(v+96))
end
return con;
end

for i,v in pairs(convert(text)) do
print(v)
end` 
But if i input 1,2 it errors out

Comment: So I guess what I need to do is convert the string that io.read() outputs into several arguments? I have no clue

Answer (score 11):

You can use [string.byte](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) and [string.char](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.char) functions:

```
string.char(97) == "a"
string.byte("a") == 97
```

If you want to start from "a" (97), then just subtract that number:

```
local function ord(char)
  return string.byte(char)-string.byte("a")+1
end
```

This will return 1 for "a", 2 for "b" and so on. You can make it handle "A", "B" and others in a similar way.

If you need number-to-char, then something like this may work:

```
local function char(num)
  return string.char(string.byte("a")+num-1)
end
```

Comment: This is doing the reverse of what i want, I want number to char not char to number.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to come up with it using the functions I listed; added to the answer (assuming the `num` starts from 1 for character "a").

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to these answers, you could store each letter in a table and simply index the table:

```
local letters = {'a','b','c'} --Finish

print(letters[1], letters[2], letters[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your encoding as follows:

```
encoding = [[abc...]]
```

in whatever order you want.
Then use it as follows

```
function char(i)
   return encoding:sub(i,i)
end
```

If the list of numbers is in a table, then you may use

```
function decode(t)
   for i=1,#t do t[i]=char(t[i]) end
   return table.concat(t)
end
```

You can also save the decoding in a table:

```
char = {}
for i=1,#encoding do char[i]=encoding:sub(i,i) end
```

and use `char[t[i]]` in `decode`.

Comment: So I have `encoding = [[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]]
i = io.read()
function char(i)
   return encoding:sub(i,i)
end
function decode(t)
   for i=1,#t do t[i]=char[i] end
   return table.concat(t)
end

print(char(i))` the thing is if i enter 1,2 it errors